# How to update select items based on the selection from the first select items using react

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have an array of objects like this:

```
 const items = [ 
  { country:"USA", level:1},
  { country:"Canada", level:2},
  { country:"Bangladesh", level:3},
]
```

And in my Form component( I am using React Formik library)I am rendering the items like this:

```
     <Field name="color" as="select" placeholder="Favorite Color">
         {items.map((item,index)=>(
           <option>{item.country}</option>
         ))}
    </Field>
    <Field name="color" as="select" placeholder="Favorite Color">
         {items.map((item,index)=>(
           <option>{item.level}</option>
         ))}
    </Field>
```

Now,I need to update the value of second select items based on the items selection from the first select input. For example, when I will select "USA" from the first selection then in the second selection it will update the value and render "1". Any ideas or suggestion would be highly appreciated.
So far, my component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Field } from 'formik';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const AddNewForm = () => {
const items = [ 
  { country:"USA", level:1},
  { country:"Canada", level:2},
  { country:"Bangladesh", level:3},
]
const handleUpdate = () => {
  console.log("change value...")
}
return (
    <div>
  <Formik
  initialValues={{ country: '', level: '' }}
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 400);
  }}
>
  {({
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    isSubmitting,
    /* and other goodies */
  }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="country" as="select" onChange={handleUpdate}>
         {items.map((item,index)=>(
           <option>{item.country}</option>
         ))}
    </Field>
    <Field name="level" as="select">
         {items.map((item,index)=>(
           <option>{item.level}</option>
         ))}
    </Field>
    <Modal.Footer>
    <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
        Save
      </button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
    </div>
)
```

}export default AddNewForm;

Comment: Are you using class or function components?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Do you have created the onChange/onSelect method of the Field component?

Comment: I am using functional component and added the component I have been using so far,Yes I understand I should pass an onChange handler method but not sure what will be the logic there to accomplish that

Comment: Can you please create a replica of this issue on code sandbox or anywhere else?
So that I can look into the errors if any.

Comment: @ManishSundriyal, here is the sandbox link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wp4tmq that we have been trying to fix. It had still one issue with the "level" field. Even though the value of level is filtered based on the selection of country, the value passed on OnSubmit remains empty unless we change the values from the "level" field. would be nice if you can help us with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I wrote earlier ... **there is no need to manage states manually, Formik manages it for us**.

Version with functional conponents/hooks - `useFormikContext` (and `<Formi />` as parent/context provider) is needed when `<Field/>` is used. You can use `useFormik` (and no parent) with normal html inputs.

Outer component:

```
export default function App() {
  const items = [
    { country: "USA", level: 1 },
    { country: "USA", level: 5 },
    { country: "Canada", level: 2 },
    { country: "Canada", level: 4 },
    { country: "Bangladesh", level: 2 },
    { country: "Bangladesh", level: 7 }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>connected selects</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ country: "", level: "" }}
        onSubmit={values => {
          console.log("SUBMIT: ", values);
        }}
      >
        <Form data={items} />
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Outer component (parent `<Formik />`) responsibility:

- initialization
- main handlers (submit)
- validation

Inner component responsibility:

- data passed as prop;
- local data filtering (avoiding unnecessary recalculations with hooks);
- local handlers for field dependencies;
- visual conditional changes

Inner component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Field, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

const AddNewForm = props => {
  const items = props.data;

  // derived data, calculated once, no updates
  // assuming constant props - for changing useEffect, like in levelOptions
  const [countryOptions] = useState(
    Array.from(new Set(items.map(item => item.country)))
  );
  const [levelOptions, setLevelOptions] = useState([]);

  const {
    values,
    handleChange,
    setFieldValue,
    handleSubmit,
    isSubmitting,
    isValid // will work with validation schema or validate fn defined
  } = useFormikContext();

  const myHandleChange = e => {
    const selectedCountry = e.target.value;

    debugger;
    // explore _useFormikContext properties
    // or FormikContext in react dev tools

    console.log("myHandle selectedCountry", selectedCountry);
    handleChange(e); // update country

    // available levels for selected country
    const levels = items.filter(item => item.country === selectedCountry);
    if (levels.length > 0) {
      // update level to first value
      setFieldValue("level", levels[0].level);
      console.log("myHandle level", levels[0].level);
    }
  };

  // current values from Formik
  const { country, level } = values;

  //  calculated ususally on every render
  //
  // const countryOptions = Array.from(new Set(items.map(item => item.country)));
  // const levelOptions = items.filter(item => item.country === country);
  //
  //  converted into hooks (useState and useEffect)
  //
  useEffect(() => {
    // filtered array of objects, can be array of numbers
    setLevelOptions(items.filter(item => item.country === country));
  }, [items, country]); // recalculated on country [or items] change

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="country"
          value={country}
          as="select"
          onChange={myHandleChange} // customized handler
        >
          {!country && (
            <option key="empty" value="">
              Select Country - disappearing empty option
            </option>
          )}
          {countryOptions.map((country, index) => (
            <option key={country} value={country}>
              {country}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Field>
        {country && (
          <>
            <Field
              name="level"
              as="select"
              onChange={handleChange} // original handler
            >
              {levelOptions.map((item, index) => (
                <option key={item.level} value={item.level}>
                  {item.level}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Field>

            <Modal.Footer>
              <button type="submit" disabled={!isValid && isSubmitting}>
                Save
              </button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </>
        )}
      </form>
      <>
        <h1>values</h1>
        {country && country}
        <br />
        {level && level}
      </>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNewForm;
```

Working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-grass-hmp8p), explorable/debbugable iframe [here](https://hmp8p.csb.app/)

Does it fulfill all functional requirements ?

Comment: Seems like this is what I wanted, I will try that solution with my real functionalities soon, but for now +1 for this initially and a big thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

const AddNewForm = () => {

  const items = [
    { country: "USA", level: 1 },
    { country: "Canada", level: 2 },
    { country: "Bangladesh", level: 3 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ country: "", level: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            setSubmitting(false);
          }, 400);
        }}
      >
        {({
          values,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting
          /* and other goodies */
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="country" as="select" onChange={handleChange} >
              <option value='' defaultValue>Select Country</option>
              {items.map((item, index) => (
                <>
                <option value={item.country} >{item.country}</option>
                </>
              ))}
            </Field>
            <Field name="level" as="select" onChange={handleChange} >
            <option value='' defaultValue>Select Level</option>
              {items.filter((item)=>item.country===values.country).map((item, index) => (
                <option>{item.level}</option>
              ))}
            </Field>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                Save
              </button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNewForm;
```

Try this working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wp4tmq)

Comment: State duplication, Formik manages values internally in `values`

Comment: thanks for the solution, it was helpful to move forward with the component, Although the initially in the second drop down selection nothings appears,I was expecting if the default selection in the first drop down is "USA" then it will also render initially the corresponding level "1" in the second drop down as well

Comment: `const [selectedCountry,setSelectedCountry] = useState('')` if you provide default value in `useState`, it will. For example, try `useState('Canada')`. Initially nothing is selected.

Comment: things are working fine but now the problem is when I submit to the "Save" button it doesn't send any value

Comment: @saon you can have multiple countries with multiple levels right?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal, yes it is true although it doesn't matter but the problem is that  the "onSubmit" doesn't receive the values from the drop down

Comment: @saon I have updated the code, `onSubmit` is working now.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal thanks again, just wondering when we remove the default value from the "level"-> or remove this line: <option value='' defaultValue>Select Level</option>, why the value of level becomes empty

Comment: seems like the value "level" doesn't update unless we change the drop down items,what if we don't want to have a default options there...

Comment: @saon sorry couldn't pursue it, will look into it shortly and update you.

Comment: @saon, this was the only way I could get it to work, it has `placeholder` but for some reason, it is not working. And don't forget to mark it as answer if this was what you were looking for. :)

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal, yes I am also trying to make it work but for some reasons it didn't. thanks for trying though but I was kind of still looking for that solution...seems like even though level is filtered but unless we change the level value, the level value gets empty on onSubmit

Comment: Thanks I got this working for mine  use case where if I select something from onefield, it automatically update  the second select field with the same selected  value but is  disabled and is readonly